# What does this function return ? (sometimes same string, sometimes missing a char)

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

What does this code do exactly ?
sometimes it returns same string and sometimes the string missing a char. why is that ?

```
char *string_dup(const char *s) {
    size_t n = strlen(s);
    char *t = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
    if (t == NULL) return t;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        t[i] = s[i];
    t[n - 1] = '\0';
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Create a [mcve] of the missing char, and the non-missing char.

Comment: What part of it don't you understand, specifically? Do you know what `strlen` does? What `malloc` does? Does `t[n - 1] = '\0'` make sense? Did you try tracing through the logic with some example values?

Comment: no i understand all that but I tried to execute it as an example with a "hello", it showed "hell" first time and then it showed "hello" why is that ?

Comment: The code has multiple bugs. For a 0 length string, it tries to write before the string start. It also does not allocate enough space for the null terminator.

Comment: Well for one thing it doesn't return an exact duplicate of the source string. Use a debugger to step through the code while monitoring variables and their values to see what it actually does.

Comment: This is C, not C++

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5BJZv3IM82sliynb): I got `hell` from both first and second call. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @HongOoi It's both

Comment: OP please confirm whether you are using a C compiler or a C++ compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this code do exactly ?

It...

- Accepts a pointer to a null terminated character string.
- Allocates memory for a null terminated string that is shorter by 1 characters than the input string.
- Copies the input string into the memory excluding the null terminator.
- Writes null terminator over the last character.
- Returns the pointer to the allocated memory that contains the copied substring.

---

P.S. Avoid using malloc in C++.

P.P.S. Avoid owning bare pointers in C++.

P.P.P.S. If the input string is empty, then the behaviour of the program is undefined. Makes sense since an empty string doesn't contain a strictly shorter substring.

P.P.P.P.S. `* sizeof(char)` is redundant because `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: On point 2 I'd hammer it home that the missing character is because `strlen` doesn't count the null terminator.